# Angular: How to pass data to a specific cell in a table in a component

Tags: angular, components, cell

How can I select a single cell of a table (table is a calendar) in Angular?

Can we use the #refName, like #JanPerson1, JanPerson2 etc. and afterwards assign a property for each cell of the calendar table like JanPerson1: number, JanPerson2: number, FebPerson1: number, FebPerson2 etc. in order to fill it with the number data?

[image: Calendar picture]

Comment: Please share some code which you have tried till now.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I am in the phase of planning how to do that, so no code is written yet, any suggestion from your side would be welcomed

Comment: Please try something with whatever you have and if you stuck, drop a question regarding that. Looking at the attached screenshot looks like you need a grid control.

Comment: grid control u refer to this one https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/ ?

Comment: you can also refer this. https://stackblitz.com/angular/ybdlpdggalb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

you need use a template reference variable, but always the same to each cell, e.g.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of [0,1,2,3]">
  <td *ngFor="let cell of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]>
      <div #cell>..</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

A QueryList of cell give you all the cells order from top to down and left to rigth

```
@ViewChildren('cell') cells:QueryList<ElementRef>

getCell(row,col){
   return cells.find((_,index)=>index==(row*7+col))
}
```

If you has no a div else an component, you can use `@ViewChildren(MyCellComponent)...`